# how to retrieve JSON data as multiple objects

Tags: java, json, spring

I'm trying to add users to a group then return all those users and update their `groupid` with the group they were just added to. the trouble I'm having is I can't seem the pass the JSON data into my method to alter the `groupid` field for each user.

I've tried using `JSONObject` and `JSONArray` but since I'm not to familiar with it I'm not too sure if I used it right.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/update")
    public List<User> updateGroupID(@RequestBody List<User> incomingusers, Integer groupid) {
        List<User> newUserList = new ArrayList<User>();
        for(User updateduser : incomingusers){
            updateduser.setGroupID(groupid);
            userRepo.save(updateduser);
            newUserList.add(updateduser);
        } 
        return newUserList;
    }
```

this is the `JSON` output from the console that is sent to my method. managing multiple users is where I'm having trouble.

```
data:
0: {username: "seanuser", userTypeID: 2, groupID: null, password: "password", email: "sean@gmail.com", …}
1: {username: "noahuser", userTypeID: 2, groupID: null, password: "password", email: "noah@gmail.com", …}
groupID: 3
```

this is the code that is supposed to return the users and groupid

```
  saveGroupHandler = () => {
    const groupID= this.state.groupId;
    const updatedGroup = {...this.state.groupToEdit};
    console.log(updatedGroup)
    this.setState(state=>({groupSaved:!state.groupSaved})) 
    axios.post(`http://localhost:8080/user/update/${groupID}`,updatedGroup)
    .then(response=>console.log(updatedGroup))
    .catch(error =>console.log(error));
  }
```

I'm expecting to get those users into my List of type `User` so i can then update the `groupid`.

this is the output I'm getting:

```
Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token
```

Comment: Your json is not a valid json format.

It should be data: [ { username: "seanuser" ... etc }, { username: "noahuser"... } ]

also you can't pass body to 2 separate objects, either pass groupId as pathVariable or create a wrapper object of users + groupId.

Comment: what format is this since its not json? and how would i make a wrapper object of users + groupid?

Comment: https://jsonlint.com try this to validate if JSON is correct.
A json should start with { or [ and end with same. Try some online tool to help you use that.

A wrapper object would be a class with 2 attributes - List<User> incomingusers and Integer groupid. then later you can do wrapperObject.getIncomingusers() to get your users.

Comment: i edited my post to show some react code that sends the response. maybe that's where the issue is? it not being formatted correctly?

Comment: instead     const updatedGroup = {...this.state.groupToEdit};
try     const updatedGroup = {...this.state.groupToEdit.data};

Comment: also is the json still the same?

@PostMapping(value = "/update") this should have placeholder for groupId
@PostMapping(value = "/update/{groupid}")

Answer (score 0):

***If you have a valid JSON string as mentioned by @Taavi Kivimaa above then you can deserialize it like this:***

```
private ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<Usere> users = readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<List<User>>() {});
```

of course, you'll need to wrap it in a try-catch block.